# x-www-form-urlencoded multiple keys in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this code in ajax

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://sample.com",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": basicauth,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
        
        "key": "value1",
        "key": "value2"
      }
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

when i execute that code it only submit the value2. How can i make it submit the value1 and value2?

Comment: You can not use the same object key twice, the second one will overwrite the first. You'll probably have to build the data in string form yourself here. If you don't want to deal with the URL encoding yourself, then use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append

Comment: Can you try to add "[]" to the key: `"data":{"key[]":"value1","key[]":"value2"}`

Comment: @chrwahl yes i did but it cant find the key when i submit.

Comment: @chrwahl that still has the exact same issue - the same key used more than once in a JS object. The square brackets in the parameter name would be necessary, if the result was to be interpreted by PHP (because that will overwrite parameters of the same name on its end while parsing the data, unless that "syntax" is used), but it doesn't change anything about the JS syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having duplicate keys in an object will just have the previous values overwritten. To send multiple values with the same key with $.ajax you can pass an array as the value. By default $.ajax uses PHP style parameters so `[]` will be appended to your key, to avoid this you have to set the parameter `traditional: true`.

```
var settings = {
    "url": "https://sample.com",
    "method": "POST",
    "timeout": 0,
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": basicauth,
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "data": {
        
        "key": ["value1", "value2"]
    },
    traditional: true,
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```